# Why anchor-lang v0.29.0 introduce v1.18.3 'solana-program'?

Tags: anchor-lang, anch

I create a anchor project that only depend on `anchor-lang = "0.29.0"` in Cargo.toml
One thing I can't understand is that after cargo add or update, the 'solana-program' version inside Cargo.lock file is `v1.18.3`, this is the question. As I saw the anchor-lang's 'Cargo.toml' use dep as:

```
[dependencies.solana-program]
version = "1.16"
```

Is there any way to show how cargo resolve and use v1.18.3 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cargo`, the Rust package manager, uses [Semantic Versioning (SemVer)](https://semver.org/) when deciding which version of the dependency to install.

`anchor-lang` [uses](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/fc9fd6d24b9be84abb2f40e47ed3faf7b11864ae/lang/Cargo.toml#L55) the following version requirement for `solana-program` crate:

```
solana-program = "1.16"
```

For SemVer, this means `>= 1.16.0, < 2.0.0`, and because `cargo` resolves to the latest compatible version by default, new installations (without a lock file) currently resolve to the `1.18.3` version.

Comment: Thanks. Your conclusion is correct. I just wrote simple demo to prove it.
But the SemVer link your provided   do not have detail on on how does "x.y" resolved. Cargo may use it own SemVer flavor. I will do more search to found Cargo specified document on SemVer.